# How to Extract Jira test results data using azure data factory..?

Tags: azure-data-factory, jira-rest-api

I am facing the issue with extrct projects test results data from Jira using API in azure data factory.

Please help me on this..

Comment: Can you add some detail please? What do you have so far, what kind of error are you getting? Are you using some sort of Jira Plugin? Probably should tag it with whatever plugin you are using if so. I assume you are using xRay or Zephir or something.

Comment: Hi , Thank you for promt response,
i need to extract the test results for sinagle project using xRay api URL calling in data factory.

i need help on how to retrive the jira test results using API call..

Thank you

Comment: Have you looked at this https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAY/Tests+-+REST#TestsREST-GettingallTestsstatuses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have experience using XRAY API, but I have made other API calls via ADF. Based on Xray documentation you would need to make two API calls in ADF.

1. Get Access Token/API Key
2. Use Access Token to Get Test Results

Theoretically it would look something like this using these links:

https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAYCLOUD/Authentication+-+REST

https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAY/Tests+-+REST#TestsREST-GettingallTestsstatuses

Step 1: Get Access Token (refer to link and screenshot here)

[image: Get Access Token]

Step 2: Use Access Token to get Test Results (refer to link and screenshot)

[image: Get Test Results]

This should be pretty close to what you need, but I am unable to test since I don't use xray, but I hope this helps.